# Rstudio setwd not there when creating new file

Tags: r, rstudio

When I setwd using Rstudio IDE GUI, then I go to create a new file... the default working directory is not the current working directory. What is a better Workflow? Any .Rprofile commands to always save in the working directory?

pic 1[image]

pic 2[image]

Comment: are you using r projects? that seems like it would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using a project would certainly help. Projects will always set the working directory to the project root folder on opening. Additionally, previous commands and working environment is saved (if you want it to be), so you can get right back to where you were. This is especially useful if you are working on different assignments.

Additionally, you can use `getwd()` to get your current working directory. Remember that the RStudio file-browser doesn't update when you set your working directory in R.